# ng-show="frm.Email.$error.email " doesn't show the error of invalid email

Tags: javascript, angularjs, email

I am trying to create a login form in mvc-asp.net with angularjs validation ,

here is my code :

```
<span style="color:red" ng-show="frm.Email.$dirty || frm.Email.$invalid">
    <span ng-show="frm.Email.$error.required">ایمیل را وارد کنید</span>
    <span ng-show="frm.Email.$error.email">ایمیل وارد شده نامعتبر است</span>
</span>
```

when i leave the textbox empty the error is appeared `frm.Email.$error.required` but when i enter an invalid email `mike.com` the error of`ng-show="frm.Email.$error.email` doesn't appear.why?

Comment: Could you show your form and your input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are using

```
<input type="text">.
```

For email, you should use

```
<input type="email">.
```

To validate email address, Angular use `HTML5` `valid` and `invalid` controls.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use

```
<input type="email">
```

instead of

```
<input type="text">
```

or text with a `ng-pattern` which contains the pattern you need in that case.

P.S: dont forget to have  `<form novalidate>` in your form to avoid the HTML5 validations and apply your Angular Validations

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to provide ng-pattern attribute for the input element

Answer (score 0):

```
"form.mail.$error.email" //**form-name.input-name.$error.email**

 <form ng-app="" name="form">
 <div>
      <label>e-mail:</label><input type="email" id="mail"name="mail" ng-model="mail">
      <p><div ng-show="form.mail.$error.email">Enter the valid mail id</div></p>
 </div>
```

In ng-show i have checked the email in validation..*form* refers to name of the form tag , mail refers to name of input type email $error refers to check the error and email refers to type of the email..

Comment: @jps Thanks for the feedback..!!  in ng-show i have checked the email in validation.._form_ refers to name of the **form tag** ,  **mail** refers to name of input type email  $error refers to check the error and email refers to type of the email..